# Get value / state from html checkbox styled with css3 in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, css, checkbox, webforms

I have a styled html checkbox that sets some bools on a admin page. On hitting the "Save" button I want to get the states / values of the checkbox en update the database.

Now I know that I can add `rutan="server"` to the control but for some reason that breaks the css and the Checkbox can't be checked anymore.

So what would be the way to get the value here? Or whats the best practice?

This is a webforms app.

**switch(css / html):**

```
.cmn-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.cmn-toggle + label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  user-select: none;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round + label {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  border-radius: 60px;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round + label:before,
input.cmn-toggle-round + label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  content: "";
}
input.cmn-toggle-round + label:before {
  right: 1px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 60px;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round + label:after {
  width: 19px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: margin 0.4s;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round:checked + label:before {
  background-color: #8ce196;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round:checked + label:after {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.switch-align {
    margin-top: 5px;
}


<input id="switchAdmin" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round" type="checkbox" />
<label for="switchAdmin"></label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `runat="server"` on HTML controls, web forms by default will override the `id` attribute to be a unique and "predictable" value.

Thus, your label's `for` attribute will not match the underlying checkbox, so the `:checked` state will never be actioned.

Try converting the `<input type="checkbox" ..` to `<asp:Checkbox ID=".."` and make sure you set the `ClientIDMode` attribute of the checkbox control to `static` this will ensure that whatever value you enter into the `ID` field will not be overridden during render.

```
<asp:Checkbox ID="switchAdmin" CssClass="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round" ClientIDMode="Static" Runat="server" />
<label for="switchAdmin"></label>
```

Comment: Ah this makes things clear for me! I did not know that rutan="server" would change the control ID. Works now thanks!!